# I want exact definition for some phrases in some specific sentences

Tags: translation

I want to translate a short story for my term project from English to Persian, I face problem finding suitable equivalence for some phrases, indeed I looked them up in several English/Persian & English/English Dictionaries but unfortunately I couldn't figured the meaning out. if possible, give me the English definition of the meaning of the phrases blow.

1. ***"jilted fury":*** My brother Wallow has been kicking around Gannon’s Boat Graveyard for more than an hour, too embarrassed to admit that he doesn’t see any ghosts. Instead, he slaps at the ocean with ***jilted fury.***
2. ***"bobbing for diseases":*** I dared Wallow to put the goggles on and stick his head in it. I didn't actually expect him to find anything; I just wanted to laugh at Wallow in the pink goggles, ***bobbing for diseases***.
3. ***"Heartland":*** For brothers, Wallow and I look nothing alike. I’ve got Dad’s blond hair and blue eyes, his embraceably lanky physique. Olivia was equally ***Heartland***, apple cheeks and unnervingly white teeth. Not Wallow.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, language translation requests should be posted in [English stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/), however, this isn't so much a language question as a 'meaning' question related to a short story and so I'll answer here.

[Haunting Olivia by Karen Russel](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2005/06/13/haunting-olivia)

**"jilted fury":** The implication here is immense frustration. Wallow has been trying hard to find a ghost for "more than an hour" and surfaces from the ocean and flails in anger.  Jilted giving the impression of a cast aside lover, as if the boat graveyard has rejected him and his quest.

**"bobbing for diseases":** Bobbing for apples is an old English tradition at fetes whereby the contestant sticks their head in a barrel of water and attempts to retrieve a floating apple with their teeth.  Bobbing for diseases will mean swimming in polluted waters, catching bacteria or algae in your mouth. Good analogy.

**"Heartland":** This is meaningless but capitalized.  Therefore signifies a surname.  To say Olivia was Heartland means that she takes after her mother or father (whichever side of the family has the surname Heartland).  Poor prose in the story, likely one of their names was Heartland, eg Wallow Heartland, but this part of the story may have been edited out or omitted.